# Why does querying Azure table storage with ExecuteQuery return fewer results than ExecuteQuerySegmented?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm curious if Azure can timeout on ExecuteQuery or silently error if there is a memory limit that is causing ExecuteQuery to return fewer records than ExecuteQuerySegmented.

When I run ExecuteQuery, I get a total of 1,223,749 records.

When I run ExecuteQuerySegmented, I get a total of 1,482,504 records.

The two queries are:

(the ExecuteQuerySegmented is inside of a do/while that handles the token)

```
var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<RecordType>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, PartitionValue, token);

var query = new TableQuery<RecordType>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, PartitionValue));
results.AddRange(table.ExecuteQuery(query));
```

Comment: Please show more code, especially the do while loop.

Answer (score 0):

A call to a Table service API can include a server timeout interval, specified in the timeout parameter of the request URI. If the server timeout interval elapses before the service has finished processing the request, the service returns an error.

**The maximum timeout interval for Table service operations is 30 seconds**. The Table service automatically reduces any timeouts larger than 30 seconds to the 30-second maximum.

**The Table service enforces server timeouts as follows:**

Query operations: During the timeout interval, a query may execute for up to a maximum of five seconds. If the query does not complete within the five-second interval, the response includes continuation tokens for retrieving remaining items on a subsequent request. See Query Timeout and Pagination for more information.

I'd recommend checking the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-timeouts-for-table-service-operations).

In case if the query is taking more than 30secs, this may mean that the records shown by ExecuteQuery are caused by the timeout.